# Guard let returns me out of the function

Tags: swift

I want to do a post api call, but it never reaches the do catch block because guard let exits me out of the function. I've debugged it and I have values inside the postCompleteCall, but stil returns me out of the function. I will pass the code below:

```
 @MainActor
    func completeChangeEmail(id: String, email: String) async throws {
        networkMonitor.checkInternetConnection()
        guard let completePost = postCompleteCall(email: email) else { return }
        isLoading = true
        do {
            isLoading = false
            changeEmailModel.getChangeEmailData = try await changeEmailUseCase.completeChangeEmail(id: id, completeChangeEmailPost: completePost)
            presentingUnknownError = false
        } catch {
            presentingUnknownError = true
            isLoading = false
            RCHLog.log("Failed to get change email")
        }
    }

    private func postCompleteCall(email: String) -> CompleteChangeEmailPost? {
        changeEmailModel.completeChangeEmailPost?.variables.form.value.email = email
        return changeEmailModel.completeChangeEmailPost
    }

public struct CompleteChangeEmailPost: Codable {
    var variables: Variables

    struct Variables: Codable {
        var form: Form
        var decision: Decision
    }

    struct Decision: Codable {
        var value, type: String
    }

    struct Form: Codable {
        var value: Value
    }

    struct Value: Codable {
        var email: String
    }
}

class ChangeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared: ChangeViewModel = ChangeViewModel()

    @Published var startChangeData: StartChangeEmailAssetsData?
    @Published var getChangeEmailData: GetChangeEmailAssetsData?
    @Published var completeChangeEmailPost: CompleteChangeEmailPost?
    @Published var variablesAssetsData: VariablesAssetsData?
}
```

Comment: It's not really possible to help with this when we have no idea what changeEmailModel is and what data it contains.

Comment: Hey Exal, If `changeEmailModel.completeChangeEmailPost` is `nil`, the assignment to `changeEmailModel.completeChangeEmailPost?... = ...` won't do anything. Your `postCompleteCall` function is returning `nil`, so your code hits the `else { return }` just as you requested

Comment: @Alexander Hello, thanks for the response. I've checked one more time and you are right, the completeChangeEmailPost is nil. Should I initialise it somewhere ?

Comment: Of course you need to initialise it if you want to access the properties it contains.

Comment: I edited the post how it was "initialised".

Comment: No, that only shows how completeChangeEmailPost is declared and not how it is initialised or set. But maybe this isn't relevant to the question and that the simple answer is, as long as completeChangeEmailPost is nil your guard statement will fail because assigning a value to `completeChangeEmailPost?.variables.form.value.email` when the first link in the chain is nil will not do anything since the whole chain is then nil.